# R3 Corda and log4j dependency

Tags: corda

I could see there is a dependency with log4j and log4j-core-2.13.3.jar is embedded in corda.jar. Is there any update available or how can we fix the log4j related vulnerability

Comment: Check this R3's official Apache Log4j announcement:
https://docs.r3.com/en/release-notes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://docs.r3.com/en/release-notes.html) page provides updates on all major alerts, fixes and forthcoming patch releases. Check the top of the page for the most urgent alerts.